# A more efficient way to manage IEnumerable.GroupBy()

Tags: c#, .net-3.5, c#-3.0, lambda

This is a segue to my previous question:

[Looking for a better way to sort my List<T>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3141285/looking-for-a-better-way-to-sort-my-listt)

Basically, I have a similar situation where I need to do a .GroupBy() on about 40 different fields.

The original code would have used a giant switch statement, but I'd like to know if there's a better way to this.

What I'd really like to do is something like:

`// not sure what the GroupBy selector function def should be...


Dictionary<PortfolioMapping, Func<Holding, ???>> groupByMappings;`

which I can use to group by like:

`myPortfolioHoldings.GroupBy(groupByMaping[frmGroupBySelector.SelectedColumn]);`

What would be the correct way to go about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to group by `object`:

```
Dictionary<PortfolioMapping, Func<Holding, object>> groupByMappings;
```

This will work as long as your mapping functions return either:

- Instances of built-in types (such as number or strings)
- Objects that implement `IEquatable<T>`
- Objects that implement `Equals` and `GetHashCode` correctly

Comment: Thanks Tim! Will test & confirm, but looks like what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Well, what I personally do is build up lambda expressions and then applying the final expression to the list.

I use some extension method to Linq.Expression which just wrap something like the following:

```
<System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Extension()> _
Public Function Compose(Of T)(ByVal first As Expressions.Expression(Of T), ByVal second As Expressions.Expression(Of T), ByVal merge As Func(Of Expressions.Expression, Expressions.Expression, Expressions.Expression)) As Expressions.Expression(Of T)

    '' build parameter map (from parameters of second to parameters of first)
    Dim map = first.Parameters.[Select](Function(f, i) New With {f, .s = second.Parameters(i)}).ToDictionary(Function(p) p.s, Function(p) p.f)

    '' replace parameters in the second lambda expression with parameters from the first
    Dim secondBody = ParameterRebinder.ReplaceParameters(map, second.Body)

    '' applycomposition of lambda expression bodies to parameters from the first expression 
        Return Expressions.Expression.Lambda(Of T)(merge(first.Body, secondBody), first.Parameters)
    End Function

<System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Extension()> _
Public Function [And](Of T)(ByVal first As Expressions.Expression(Of Func(Of T, Boolean)), ByVal second As Expressions.Expression(Of Func(Of T, Boolean))) As Expressions.Expression(Of Func(Of T, Boolean))
    Return first.Compose(second, AddressOf Expressions.Expression.And)
End Function
```

And then you can build queries like this:

```
Dim MyQuery as Linq.Expressions.Expression(Of System.Func(Of MyListDataType, Boolean))
Dim MyGroupingExpression as Linq.Expressions.Expression(Of System.Func(Of MyListDataType, Boolean))

Dim MyQuery = Function(x) x.SomeValue = SomeExpectedValue
Select case SomeOtherVariable
    Case Option1
        Dim MyGroupingExpression = <blah>
    Case Option2
        Dim MyGroupingExpression = <blah>
End Select

Dim Results = MyList.Where(MyQuery.And(GroupingExpression))
```

Is that what you're after?